# MongooseJS Query select attributes of subdocument

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

Given a model `foo` with the following schema;

```
{
    a: String,
    b: [{c: String, d: String}]
}
```

Assume the values of `a` are unique, and assume the values of `c` in a given `foo` document are unique. If I had values **A** and **C** of `a` and `c` respectively, then **A** uniquely identifies a `foo` document, and **C** uniquely identifies a `foo.b` sub-document. Is it possible then, to forge a query that returns to me the value of `d`?

Conceptually,

foo ----(find({a:**A**}))-----> foo_document -----(find({c:**C**}))------>foo_subdoc-------(select(d))---->value_of_d

Enough information is given, I just don't know if Mongoose has a a mechanism for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`$elemMatch`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/projection/elemMatch/#proj._S_elemMatch) projection operator to identity the matching `b` element to include:

```js
foo.find({a: A}, {b: {$elemMatch: {c: C}}}, function(err, doc) {
    // doc.b[0].d contains the value of d you're looking for.
});
```